# How can I recover a huge folder that's been converted to a zero kb file on an NTFS partition?

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery

I have a 1TB drive with two 500GB partitions. One of them is being used as a Mac OS X Time Machine back up drive and the other one was NTFS and being used for storage. I had my entire 'iTunes Music' folder stored on it. Recently, there were some errors on the NTFS drive that caused chkdsk to run when in Windows, and it removed a lot of corrupt files. In this process, it converted my 'iTunes Music' folder into one zero KB file. How can I recover this? The partitions are intact and the other data on the disk is still accessible. It's just the 'iTunes Music' folder that's gone.